# Inappropriate tag alias created

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

I recently noticed that the [cran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cran) tag (for the [Comprehensive R Archive Network](https://cran.r-project.org/)) was made a synonym of the general R language tag, [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). I'm not sure who requested this (and there seems to have been no discussion here on meta or in [the chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106/r) for major R contributors on SO).

It seems to be an inappropriate synonym. Many other language tags are kept separate from associated repository tags ([perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl)/[cpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpan), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)/[pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pypi), [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)/[npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm), etc.). And I had been trying fairly religiously to untag [cran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cran) from all generic R questions to retain tag clarity and there were still several hundred CRAN-specific questions at last glance.

Can this synonym relationship be reversed, please?

Comment: when reading "inappropriate" I first thought this would be about something else.

Comment: @Hayt Sorry to disappoint. ;-)

Comment: I was just ready to rant about this...  :( and you have actually a valid one ;)

Comment: Given that the synonym was applied just once, I don't see problems with keeping it like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can't see why the community voted for that and although I'm not an R person - I see no reason for that synonym to exist so I've removed it.

Of course - if someone can provide a suitable reason for its existence, then comment under this answer and it can always be reinstated if needs be.